# How to write stdout from Process to HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, servlets, phantomjs

I have an external script that I launch within a `Servlet`, then read the `stdout` and finally offer the file for download.

The external script is `phantomjs`, but that should not matter for this question. Important is only that I read and write the stdout stream as follows:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("phantomjs", "rasterize.js", url);

InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

OutputStream httpStream = response.getOutputStream();
int bytes;
while ((bytes = br.read()) != -1) {
    httpStream.write(bytes);
}
```

Result: it works, but takes approx 10 seconds to write a 500kb file actually to the `OutputStream`.

Why? How could I increase the performance?

Comment: Did you try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read(char[],%20int,%20int)?

Comment: You have only the time for the full operation: execute background command, get its output, write it to HTTP response. If you want to optimize that, you should first execute separately the 3 operation: 1/ execute the command in a shell, 2/ run the command from java code and store the output to a file, 3/ read the file and copy its data to a HTTP response. Only that can show you what part is time consuming.

Comment: The time consuming part is `httpStream.write`. The rest is really quick.